# Is using "Dude" for male unknowns is rude?

Tags: synonyms, slang, informal-language

I want to know if calling strangers as a dude is rude. What are the possible alternatives?

Comment: In what context? Where? Is this at work or school or out on the street... in the US, the UK, Australia? Why "dude"?

Comment: As Catija asks, what's the context?  It's very informal and potentially rude in the wrong situation, but generally not insulting.

Comment: The context was for unknown people at work or market. The region could be US and Aisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it will be perceived as rude or lacking in deference can depend on whether you're seeking to get the stranger's attention, or you are calling him "Dude" *to his face*. When used to get someone's attention there is no disrespect implied. But when the person is called **dude** to their face, there can be a confrontational element.

> Hey dude, do you know when the train is supposed to arrive here?
>
> Dude, you're taking up more than your share of the seat. .

The same is true with almost any synonym  for **dude** that has been used over the decades:

> Hey buddy, do you know when the train is supposed to arrive here?
>
> Buddy, you're taking up more than your share of the seat.

The relative ages of the speaker and person spoken to also come into play.  A guy in his twenties is not likely to accost a man as old as his own grandfather with the word **dude**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little rude/hostile to my ears, yeah.

I think it's because calling somebody 'dude' assumes some familiarity. Using a familiar term with a stranger could come across as confrontational, or maybe as trying to seem better than the listener.

This is also true for 'bro', 'buddy', 'guy', or any of those kinds of words.